# MATLAB return image frames from video

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I have a function that processes a video and return a couple of images from it.

I am doing so by creating a new video inside the function containing the frames I want and returning the video and is the next function I read the video again to process it.

Is there any faster way to do it? For e.g. returning an array with the images and reading them?

Comment: What do you mean by "video"? Isn't it just a 3-D array of decoded frames?

Comment: I am not familiar with how to do it...
How to add the images to array and read them from that array one by one

Comment: I currently create a new video and decode it into frames again! I think array would be easier and less costly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the decoded frames as a 3-D array. For instance, if you have two 2-D frames `frame1` and `frame2`, you can concatenate them along the third dimension like so:

```
M = cat(3, frame1, frame2);
```

To extract the frames from the 3-D array, just specify the third coordinate. For example, to get `frame1`, you write:

```
frame1 = M(:, :, 1);
```

This allows you circumvent the issue of encoding and decoding the frames between function calls, as well as prevent any loss in video quality due to successive encoding.